# Why am I failing to display a texture in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to load a texture in OpenGL, but all I get is black. I've verified that the shaders are returning GL_TRUE when they compile. So, I don't think that is the issue...

Some things to note:

I have taken and modified code from https://open.gl/content/code/c3_multitexture.txt. This was a tutorial from https://open.gl/textures

The texture I am trying to load is from a 640 x 400 PGM file. You can assume the loader pgmImage correctly loads the file (I have verified it in GDB). PGM is 8-bit B&W data. Here I am trying to just use it as the red channel, although I'd like to be able to eventually display it as B&W, too.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Code compiled with: -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm -lGLEW flags in g++ (some aren't necessary, I know).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

//Glut
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include "shader.hpp"
#include "PGM.hpp"

GLuint programID;
GLuint output_image;

// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource =
    "#version 450 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "in vec2 texcoord;"
    "out vec2 Texcoord;"
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "    Texcoord = texcoord;"
    "    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
    "#version 450 core\n"
    "in vec2 Texcoord;"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "uniform sampler2D texData;"
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "    outColor = texture(texData, Texcoord);"
    "}";



void display()
{

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();

}    


void reshape(int width,int height)
{
    double w2h = (height>0) ? (double)width/height : 1;
    //  Set viewport as entire window
    glViewport(0,0, width,height);

}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Image setup

    PGM pgmImage;
    pgmImage.ReadFile("test.pgm");

    // Window Setup

    glutInitWindowSize(640, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition (140, 140);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL Application" );
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Vertices & texture init

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // X    Y      S    T
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
         0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    GLuint elements[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create shaders

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);


    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Vertex data specification
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void *)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    // Load Textures

    //TODO: don't really need 2 textures, but just following along with example source code for now...
    GLuint textures[2];
    unsigned char* image;

    int width, height;

    width = pgmImage.GetWidth();
    height = pgmImage.GetHeight();
    image = (unsigned char *)pgmImage.GetData();

    glGenTextures(2, textures);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,  GL_RED_INTEGER,  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);


    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "texData"), 0);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Start program

    glutMainLoop();

    // Teardown

    glDeleteTextures(2, textures);

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At some point, texture sizes had to be powers of 2; not sure if this is still relevant in some contexts today. Did you try checking glGetError after glTexImage2D? Did you try a constant color fragment shader instead to check the coordinates are on the screen?

Comment: Thanks for replying! Coordinates are on the screen. I get a blue background with a black box where my quad is. You're right about the powers of 2, but I read that this doesn't matter in OpenGL 4.5 (could be wrong). I'll give a look at what glError says and reply back.

Comment: There was an invalid operation on the glTexImage2D call. The format and internalformat parameters needed to match. I set format to GL_R8UI, which gets rid of the error, but I am still getting a black quad (no texture).

Comment: Also, I changed the shader to just do "outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)" ans that works correctly.

Comment: Yes, those formats are incompatible. Try `GL_RED` instead of `GL_RED_INTEGER` for the format.

Comment: @Maxthecat: "*The format and internalformat parameters needed to match. I set format to GL_R8UI, which gets rid of the error, but I am still getting a black quad (no texture).*" Then update your post to show the correct state of your code.

Comment: @StefanHaustein: Non power of two textures are allowed since OpenGL 2.0 which is now more than 12 years old.

Comment: If you want greyscale in the end anyway, I'd try  `GL_LUMINANCE` instead of `GL_RED_INTEGER`. @BDL I feel old now... :-/

Comment: NicolBolas: Hah! Sorry, I forgot you could edit questions on this site! Thanks. In any event, @RetroKoradi is correct. Those were incompatible formats. Changing GL_RED_INTEGER to GL_RED works, as does GL_LUMINANCE. Retro Koradi, do you want to submit that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you had already found, the *internalFormat* and *format* of your `glTexImage2D()` call are incompatible:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

`GL_RED_INTEGER` is for integer texture types. For 1-component texture data with normalized textures, the correct format is `GL_RED`:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

For new code, I would always recommend to use sized internal types, even though unsized internal types like `GL_RGB` are still valid for backwards compatibility. So for a normalized texture with 3 8-bit components:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

Your attempt at using `GL_R8UI` as the internal format failed because using integer textures requires additional changes, particularly in the shader code, where you would need to use `usampler2D` as the sampler type, and deal with getting integer values when you sample the textures. But in your case, that's not really what you wanted in the first place.